# C++ Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04 unable to resolve after upgrade

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

After upgrading to 12.04, my Eclipse that I had since 11.10 has been full of errors at start up. Now, it can't resolve standard stuff like fprintf, clock, and time, even though the exact same project compiled on 11.10 and I triple checked the includes being.... included.
I already clear the Discovery options for C, C++ in both Debug and Release.... still the same. (though after the first clear, things got better, as the issue was worse before, with it not even knowing of the includes)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If I just ignore the errors, and then run, it will be an updated binary so, now it's mostly a cosmetic error apparently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on your project and choose Index -> Update with Modified Files

Comment: Accepted because I had already forgotten about this, and on new projects it doesn't happen, and this sounds like it should work for other people.